# matching of two columns using R

Tags: r

I have 2 ms-excel files, in file-1 I have 2 columns namely ID and USER. Both ID and USER have 99 values. ID column has entry values from 10121 to 10219. USER columnn has total 5 kind of values(i.e categories) A1001,A1002,A1003,A1004,A1005 ( repeated randomly 99 times and matched with values of ID column)

I have another Ms-excel file, file-2 in which I have 62 ID's from 99 ID values which were given in ms-excel file-1.

I want to match the 62 ID values of file-2 with values of USER column in file-1 (in the same pattern in which the file-1 ID values are matched with file-1 USER values). could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use merge. So read in the files as file1 and file2 and then:

```
file2 = merge(x = file2, y = file1, by = "id")
```

And then it will perform an inner join based on the ID, and so you will get the user column from file1.